# Logback: How to remove class names and log level from Log file?

Tags: java, spring, logging, spring-boot, logback

I am using `Logback` in my `Spring boot` application.

In my log file I currently get the sample output:

```
16:09:43.299 [pool-2-thread-1] INFO  c.b.r.h.k.s.myClassName - Log message
```

How can I change my log settings so that it only looks like the following:

```
16:09:43.299 Log message
```

I.e removing the `"[pool-2-thread-1] INFO"` from the log statement.

Comment: Can you post your `logback.xml` file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're using Spring Boot default console and file logs, i.e. haven't any `logback.xml` in your classpath, you can use `logging.pattern.console` and `logging.pattern.file` properties. For example, adding this to your `application.yml` file will do the trick for you:

```
logging:
  pattern:
    file: '%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %msg%n'
```

Otherwise, add this pattern to your corresponding file appender in your `logback.xml`:

```
<pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} %msg%n</pattern>
```

Comment: I don't have an application.yml file, just a logback.xml file?

Comment: @java123999 If your questions is answered you should accept this.